# Compare two Dates in SAPUI5

Tags: date, sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to compare, whether Date A is greater than Date B. But I always get false, even if Date A is greater.

```
var oDatepicker = this.getView().byId("Date");
            var oFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getInstance({ pattern: "d.M.y" });
            var oDate = oFormat.format(new Date());
            var oDatepickerParsed = oFormat.parse(oDatepicker.getValue());
            if(oFormat.format(oDatepickerParsed) > oDate){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;   
            }
```

I tried to instantiate a Date-Object based on oDatepicker.getValue() to compare Date-Object with Date-Object, but there is something wrong.

```
var oDateObject = new Date(oDatepicker.getValue())
```

oDatepicker.getValue() is = '01.11.2020' type string. Whats wrong?

Comment: What is the actual goal? Just trying to avoid a possible [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The "if(oFormat.format(oDatepickerParsed) > oDate)" seems comparing two string. Suggest you use Date type for compare.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the [DatePicker](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker) method `getDateValue()` which gives you "the date as JavaScript Date object. This is independent from any formatter."